# Does web2py absolutely require a sequentially numbered id column in database tables

Tags: database, auto-increment, web2py

I have a mySQL database which is accessed by web2py, but has one table (which has an auto increment column labelled 'id') which is also regularly altered by another script. This script frequently deletes and inserts new rows into the table, so that although the integers in the 'id' column are unique and ascending, there are also many intermediate numbers missing. Will this cause web2py problems in the future?

Note that I only access this table through a different column, which contains a different set of unique identifiers, so I don't really need the 'id' column at all: it's only there because the docs state that web2py requires it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having missing values in the id field would not affect web2py by any means. but deleting or changing an ID of a record while you are editing this record in web2py would result in an error. so just be careful your web2py users are not editing records during script is changing/deleting IDs.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. In this case, web2py only has read-access to this table, so that should be fine.

Comment: Also, note that "intermediate numbers missing" is the norm for web2py DAL `id` fields, as they are standard auto-incrementing integer fields as implemented by each database -- so it is expected that when records are deleted, there will be gaps in the sequence. web2py simply requires a unique integer primary key field whose values will be filled in automatically by the database (there isn't really any requirement for the values to be sequential).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anthony. It might be useful to note this somewhere in the web2py docs. I couldn't find it specifically stated anywhere that there is no strict requirement that id numbers are sequential, although I suspect that it might have been implied at some point.

Comment: The documentation simply says, "Every table has a field called 'id' by default. It is an auto-increment integer field (starting at 1) used for cross-reference and for making every record unique, so 'id' is a primary key." I don't think it says anywhere that at all times all record ids must be in perfect sequence with no gaps, as that would not make sense and is not how auto-incrementing integer fields work.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but also note that depending on your use case, you might not need the auto-incrementing integer `id` field in your table at all, as the DAL can handle other types of primary keys via the `primarykey` argument to `db.define_table()`. In particular, if you are working with a read-only table and any references are to/from other keyed tables, you do not need the `id` field. For more details, see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Legacy-databases-and-keyed-tables.